# How to use Multi Image Picker with Image Cropper

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am currently using the dart multi-image picker plugin to select multiple photos in the app I am working on. When returning you get a list of Asset. I am trying to convert the Asset into a File to allow the image cropper to display the image correctly. Any idea on how to implement this conversion properly?

Comment: Can you explain more, what I understood is you  want to crop multiple.

Comment: @Mangaldeep I am getting multiple photos then when the user taps on a photo I am trying to open the image cropper. Since the image cropper needs a File object I am trying to convert the Asset object that comes from the multi image picker into a File object.

Comment: Have you solved this?